# Error in automatically generated XSD scheme: global element 'configuration' has already been declared

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, xsd-validation

When automatically creating a scheme for app.config, an app.xsd is generated.

However in the beginning fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
```

I get the warning:

```
Warning (line 1)    The global element 'configuration' has already been declared.
```

When I double click on the warning, the focus is on the fragment:

Does anybody have a solution how to get rid of this warning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add (Sample) XML here? The problem looks local, however can be resolved once we know XML.

Comment: Are you getting this warning while validating an XML against this schema, or while validating the XSD file itself (using some sort of an XSD validator)?

Comment: I get the error when building. However I don't get th e error anymore, probably after a reboot of the system.

Comment: It's not clear from the question title or body that the problem is specific to Visual Studio. The tags are helpful, but they're not as salient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if this is related to the problem that prompted this question, but I was encountering the same type of error ("warning") in the program [XML Notepad](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7973) and closing and then re-opening it resolved the errors I was observing like restarting your computer did for your own errors.

Comment: It might be but I cannot tell anymore since I don't have the problem anymore. Still upvoted because it might be valuable for others.